# How to reverse a string using .replace() in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, reverse

My code is suppose to replace every character in str1 with the character in str2 so in the end str1 and str2 have the same value. Can someone please explain why this is not working? it works until x=2 and from x=3 and forth the code gets crazy and just add nonsense.

```
str1, str2= "Donkey", "Yeknod"

for x in range(len(str1)): 
    str1=str1.replace(str1[x], str2[x])
```

Comment: `replace` is entirely the wrong tool to reverse a string, so I'm not sure you're going to get much of an answer to your question as you're asking it. Is there a reason you don't want to use `str1[::-1]` (or even just `str1 = str2`, if you already have the reversed form available)?

Answer (score 1):

These are your first three replacements, which happen to work how you intended:

```
replace('D', 'Y') --> Yonkey
replace('o', 'e') --> Yenkey
replace('n', 'k') --> Yekkey
```

After this point, you start replacing characters that occur multiple times in `str1`.

```
replace('k', 'n') --> Yenney
replace('e', 'o') --> Yonnoy
replace('y', 'd') --> Yonnod
```

`replace` is not a suitable method to use to reverse a string, because it replaces all matching characters, not just the one you wanted to replace.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense why the code behaved like it did!